# doubt in calculation of limits

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, cauchy-principal-value

i am solving the follwong integral using [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Formulation) 
$$ \int_{-\infty }^\infty { y\over \sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2}} dy $$ the integral of this comes out to be 
$$ \ln \left ( \left | \sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2} + y -b \right | \right ) + \sqrt {(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2} + C $$

the first of integral becomes 0   and applying limits second part becomes 
$$ \sqrt {(L-a)^2 - (x-b)^2} - \sqrt {(-L-a)^2 - (x-b)^2}$$

Can i consider the second part equal to 0 because if L is very large number then L+a and L-a will be approximately same and whole expression will become 0 .

Will this assumption is correct or total blunder . thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

No, you definitely can't do that.  While $L+a$ and $L-a$ are "approximately the same" in the relative sense that $\frac{L-a}{L+a}\approx 1$, here we're taking a difference, not a quotient.  Indeed, for any $L$, $(L-a)-(L+a)=-2a$, so $$\lim_{L\to\infty}((L-a)-(L+a))=\lim_{L\to\infty}-2a=-2a.$$

Comment: thanks !. That means in my case limit will remain to undefine  and integral still remains divergent.